# SSIS - How to add a sql column in between a flat file source and an OLE DB Destination?

Tags: ssis

I need to use a sql query to get a result to add as a column into my OLD DB destination.  I have a flat file source that contains the majority of the columns needed.

Is there a way to add a sql column in between a flat file source and an OLE DB Destination?

I can always just add another data flow, but was curious if it could be done in the same data flow.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Lookup Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15)